# unable to connect to sql server analysis services on windows vista

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms, sql-server

I just installed sql server 2008 developer edition on my windows vista machine. The installation was successful. Reporting service is working fine. But I am not getting any option to connect to "Analysis Services" in sql management studio.

The only options i get for "Server Type" while connecting are -

```
1. Database Engine
2. Sql Server Compact
```

Pls. suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Stupid question: did you install Analysis Services? Is it running in the list of Windows Services?

Comment: @Radolph Potter: Yes, I did install it. Also I can see the service running in the services.msc window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you must have installed Management Studio with only the Basic option selected.  You need to install the "Complete" option in order to have support for Analysis Services.  You should be able to just add the feature through the installer.

[alt text http://lh6.ggpht.com/kendal.vandyke/SM3LPgl2lnI/AAAAAAAAARo/f9m3hbY74Xk/s1600-h/image42[1].png](http://lh6.ggpht.com/kendal.vandyke/SM3LPgl2lnI/AAAAAAAAARo/f9m3hbY74Xk/s1600-h/image42[1].png)

Comment: If that doesn't work, then this did for me...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216482/cant-install-sql-server-2008-r2-management-tool-complete